# Text fields & gridview didn't update while CRUD performing operations winforms devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, gridview, devexpress

In my simple form, I have **Gridview** & few Text fields (**EditText**) are available, for that data is filled from **MS Access** database while form **loads**. I have few buttons for **CRUD Operation**. After performing **New record** or **Modify record** or **Delete record** (In separate / new Form) I have code to ***update / refresh*** this **Gridview** & **EditText**. But this code doesn't works here. If i use **BreakPoint** & check means it working fine, but Automatically data didn't updates from MS Access datadase. After **repoening** same form then only it will get updates or Keep one **refresh** button after pressing it will get updates. What wrong with this code ?? Please help me to solve this.. Thanks in advance.

```
BillDetails frm = new BillDetails(EditText1.Text, code1, mode);
frm.ShowDialog();

string qry = "SELECT BillId, BillNo, BillDate, BillDescription, BillAmount, DeductionAmount, AmountPaid FROM TblCoverLetterDetail WHERE chq_id=" + EditText2.Text;
Appset.FillGrid(gridControl1, qry);
gridView1.Columns["BillId"].Visible = false;
```

this above code for filling Gridview after CURD (Create Operation).

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: What does the Appset.FillGrid function do? That isn't a built in function is it? Could you show the code if it isn't built in?

Comment: Its simple way to fill data to **GridView**.

Comment: In my experience with gridviews, you have to rebind the data whenever something changes. I use the .DataSource to set my gridviews value, then .DataBind to refresh/create it.

Comment: Yeah am rebinding only using this **Appset.FillGrid** function call.